# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException when deploying spring-boot app to cloud foundry

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

**When I try to run the app on my local machine it works fine**

**But when I deploy the app to cloud foundry I see the following in the log**

```
org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException-->org.cloudfoundry.router.ClientCertificateMapperAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7ac26b9c.CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS([Lorg.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback;)
```

In my mainfist.yml the stack is set to **cflinuxfs3** and the build pack is **java_buildpack**

I'm using **spring-boot-starter-parent** version **2.2.2.RELEASE**

When searching for java build packs in cf `cf buildpacks | grep java_buildpack` I get the following

```
buildpack, position, enabled, locked, filename, stack
java_buildpack, 2, true, false, ava-buildpack-offline-cflinuxfs3-v4.26.zip, cflinuxfs3
```

Full Stack trace

```
   2020-01-17 20:35:37.304 ERROR 20 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
   org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException-->org.cloudfoundry.router.ClientCertificateMapperAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7ac26b9c.CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS([Lorg.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback;)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer$EnhancerFactoryData.<init>(Enhancer.java:510) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.wrapCachedClass(Enhancer.java:803) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:111) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[app/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:569) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:416) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:137) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:429) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:263) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:130) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140) [app/:na]
    at APP_PACKAGE.APP_NAME.main(APP_NAME.java:52) [app/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [app/:na]
   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.cloudfoundry.router.ClientCertificateMapperAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7ac26b9c.CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS([Lorg.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback;)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getCallbacksSetter(Enhancer.java:909) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.access$000(Enhancer.java:93) ~[app/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer$EnhancerFactoryData.<init>(Enhancer.java:499) ~[app/:na]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
   Exit status 0
```

Comment: What version of the CF Java buildpack are you using (i.e. what version is on your CF) and what version of Spring Boot?

Comment: @ScottFrederick I think by setting it to java_buildpack it uses the latest version
As for Spring-boot, I'm using version 2.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: Can you include the full output of `cf push`? As well as the output of `cf buildpacks | grep java_buildpack`. That will show the version of the Java buildpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed when I removed spring dev-tools dependency